# Area under the curve $f(x) = \sin x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find the area under the curve $f(x) = \sin x$ on the interval $[0, \pi]$ if $\sin x \ge 0$

My handbook give this as

$$\int_0^\pi \sin x \space dx = (\cos \pi) - (\cos 0) = (-1) - (-1) = 2$$

what bothers me is that $\sin$ is not the derivative of $\cos$, should the answer not be

$$\int_0^\pi \sin x \space dx = (-\cos \pi) - (-\cos 0) = 1 - 1 = 0$$

Comment: The handbook's answer is wrong, $\cos \pi - \cos 0 = -2$. And $(-\cos \pi) - (-\cos 0) = (-(-1)) - (-1) = 1-(-1) = 2$.

Comment: Note that a sketch will show that the answer cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\cos x=-\sin x$, hence,
$$\int^\pi_0\sin xdx=-\left.\cos x\right|^\pi_0=1-(-1)=2$$

Answer (score 1):

In fact the last part of your second equation should be:$$\ldots=1-(-1)=2$$ :)